# Adding a Free Gift to Magento Cart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am making a magento webshop for clothes. and i have 3 different coupons. so if the customers enter one of this coupons, they get different "gifts" .

E.G.
Client nathaniel enters coupon d8f8sadf8 and his cart price higher then 50€, then he gets a free wristband.

OR

Client max enters coupon 2931209f and his cart price is higher then 50€, then he gets a free wristband AND 5% discount to his cart price.

I was trying to make it with cart price rules, but nothing realy works.

has anyone ever made something like this? If you know an extension which does this, i would also be happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write a module for this.

The logic is simple. Whenever a coupon is applied, the event **salesrule_validator_process** is dispatched by Magento. Your module should listen to this event using an observer.

From the observer, you can get the **quote** object using which you can get the rule details including the **coupon code**. Now you can programmatically add the product you wish to the cart. If you are not familiar with this, use Google to research about each tasks I said and do it. Trust me, you will love it :-)